# How do I record the time every time I log on and log off of Windows XP?

Tags: windows, logging, time, events

I notice that Windows XP Event Viewer show a list of typical actions under System logs every time I start or shutdown Windows, and I can tell when my day starts and ends.

Is there anyways I can record the time every time I lock my screen and every time I re-login? There maybe a way to fool System Event Logger into submission, but a free third party tool would be good too if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought [this post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31913289/screen-saver-lock-event-i.aspx) had some interesting thoughts about this subject.  You might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely schedule a task to run when you log on or off.  Just write a little script to append a file with the system time and schedule it to run when you log on or off.

Answer (score 2):

Your Security Event Log records account logon and logoff events. Not sure if screensaver locking then logging on again counts as a loggable event though.

Timesnapper might be the thing you're looking for:

http://www.timesnapper.com/

Keep track of your day, even tracks when you're not using the computer.

Not free but at $24 hardly breaking the bank either.